# Eclipse plugin: How to add items to a TableViewer asynchronously?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jface, tableviewer

In my Eclipse plugin, I have a `TableViewer` that shows some data. These data is retrieved from a remote REST service. Therefore it takes some seconds to retrieve all items. That's why I wanted to add items to the `TableViewer`'s `ContentProvider` as soon as I retrieve them. I do my REST query in a separate thread:

```
Thread retrieveThread = new RetrieveThread();
retrieveThread.run();
```

In this thread I add items to my `TableViewer`:

```
MyView.instance.addItems(items);
```

And the same method in the class `MyView`:

```
public void addItems(List<Result> items) {
    ModelProvider.INSTANCE.addItems(items);
    resultLabel.setText(ModelProvider.INSTANCE.getItems().size() + " items");
    PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            viewer.refresh();
        }
    });
}
```

I expected that this procedure will add items to my `TableViewer` and then refresh the view. But what happens now is that my Eclipse freezes and adds all them items at the same time. How can I do this in a more responsive way?

Comment: Can you add here the source code of your RetrieveThread and MyView ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are calling the `run` method of your thread directly. This does not spawn a new thread, it just calls the run method in-line. `retrieveThread.start()` would give you the behaviour you are looking for.

However, there is a better way of doing it (at least more 'eclipse friendly'), and that is to use an Eclipse `Job` instead of a raw `Thread`.

```
    Job retrieveJob = new Job("Retrieving Data") 
    {           
        @Override
        protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
            // do your REST call
            ModelProvider.INSTANCE.addItems(items);
            // if something goes wrong - don't return ok, obviously 
            return Status.OK_STATUS;                
        }
    };
    retrieveJob.addJobChangeListener(new JobChangeAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void done(IJobChangeEvent event) {
            if(event.getResult().isOK())
            {
                resultLabel.setText(ModelProvider.INSTANCE.getItems().size() + " items");
                viewer.refresh();
            }
        }           
    });
    // this will run in a background thread 
    // and nicely integrate with the UI
    retrieveJob.schedule();
```